# How to design a database table(s) for recording email changes?

Tags: postgresql

The requirements:

1. User needs to confirm their email after signing up
2. User needs to confirm their email after changing their email before this email is activated

My understanding is that the schema for this should look something like:

```
email_address (id, email_address)
user_account (id, email_address_id, activated_at)
email_address_authentication_token (id, email_address_id, user_account_id, token, used_at)
```

When user creates account, we create records in these tables:

```
email_address (1, 'foo@bar.com')
user_account (1, 1, null)
email_address_authentication_token (1, 1, 1, 'XXX', null)
```

When user confirm their email address, then we *activate* `user_account` and mark token as *used*.

When user change their email address, then we create a new entry in `email_address_authentication_token` and when they confirm it, we update `user_account_id` `email_address_id`.

Does this seem logical?

Comment: Looks ok to me, but the question is, does it work with your use case requirements? Can 1 email address be used for more than 1 account? How would typical queries cope with that given your model. when a user logs in, do they use an acct no or email address?

Comment: Only 1 active email address can be associated with the account. They use their email address when they attempt to login.

Comment: I understand an account can only have 1 email. But can many accts use the same email address?

Comment: They cannot, no.